# Create a function to generate negative binomial random variables in R

Tags: r

This is for homework, so `rnbinom` doesn't help.

I've created two functions: `combr` (combinations with repetitions) and another called `negbinom`.

```
combr <- function(k,r) {
  return(factorial(k+r-1) / (factorial(r) * factorial (k-1)))
  }

negbinom <- function(k,r,p){
  return(combr(k,r)*(p^k)*((1-p)^r))
  }
```

`Negbinom` generates a single number. How do I create a function in order to generate `n` random numbers by recalling `negbinom` `n` times. Or similarly, how do I create my own "rnbinom"?

Comment: Wouldn't be just possible to encapsulate the function within a loop `for (t in 1:times) { }` and then push things to a results vector `vecRes[t]` that would be returned at the end?

Comment: Are you implementing `rnbinom` or `dnbinom` or `pnbinom`? You don't seem to have any random elements... at this point `rep(negbinom(k, r, p), n)` would work as well as calling the function multiple times.

Comment: So we have two issues. 1) They want to do random sampling (which would have been more appropriate to discuss on the stats site and 2) they want to vectorize or provide a new parameter that dictates the result length (which is sort of appropriate here).  Question still needs to be cleaned up and expanded upon to give the details of the actual issue at hand.

Comment: I migrated this here without noticing the first issue, which has now been dealt with in a new question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/215808/17230). Sorry about that.